# Empty figure window when using stairs function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Here is one example from Mathworks site:

Create a stairstep plot of sine evaluated at 40 equally spaced values between 0 and 4pi.

Here is code:

```
X = linspace(0,4*pi,40);
Y = sin(X);
figure
stairs(Y)
```

Result should be:

[image: screenshot]

However, I don't get that graph - I get empty window (figure). 
Any idea?

Edit:
If I do this:

```
y=stairs(Y)
```

I get:

```
y = 

  Stair with properties:

              Color: [0 0.4470 0.7410]
          LineStyle: '-'
          LineWidth: 0.5000
             Marker: 'none'
         MarkerSize: 6
    MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
              XData: [1x40 double]
              YData: [1x40 double]

  Show all properties
```

Comment: Did you make sure to hit the enter key *after* copy/pasting that into MATLAB to ensure that the last line is actually run?

Comment: Sure :)  Really have no idea whats wrong...

Comment: What does `which('stairs')` give you? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get this C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\stairs.m

Comment: Are you calling the above code from the command line or a script or a function?

Comment: I call it from command line. Please refresh, I edited my post. Maybe informations I added will help :)

Comment: what if you call `figure(ancestor(y, 'figure'))` after calling `y = stairs(Y);`

Comment: Nothing happens :(

Comment: No clue. It looks like everything is working based on what you have posted.

Comment: I can't replicate the empty window issue. Have you tried relaunching Matlab?

Comment: Yes :)  I will restart PC now.

Comment: Still same problem... Really strange.